# How to: substring of a column in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

all. I had a SQL Server table with a column named "Name". I want to query the rows if the "Name" substract the last char are in a list.
Here is my SQL query but it tell me error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

```
select * from MyTable where substring(Name, 1, len(Name) - 1) in ('ABC', 'DEF')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the length of your "Name" first, if the name is empty, substring(Name, 1, len(Name) - 1) will throw error.

Answer (score 3):

How about doing something like this?

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where name like 'ABC_' or name like 'DEF_';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the root cause, because some of the value of the "Name" column are empty, so len(Name) will throw an error during executing.